# Date is not inserting into the database correctly

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring Framework and Hibernate as ORM Tool. Whenever i am inserting a date into the database the date is not correctly being inserted. For example 
The problem i am facing is that if i give input

2016/10/20 
In the database it is being stored like
2016/10/19 .( One day difference.). I am using SimpleDateFormat to format the date coming as input from the form being submitted by the user. I just want to store Date not TIMESTAMP. Below is my Controller and Model Code.

```
package com.bbms.web.controllers;

import com.bbms.web.models.BloodBag;
import com.bbms.web.models.donor.DonorPersonalInformation;
import com.bbms.web.services.BloodBagService;
import com.bbms.web.services.DonorService;
import com.bbms.web.validators.BloodBagValidator;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/blood-bag")
public class BloodBagController {

    @Autowired
    private DonorService donorService;

    @Autowired
    private BloodBagValidator bloodBagValidator;

    @Autowired
    private BloodBagService bloodBagService;

    private BloodBag bloodBag;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "collectionDate", new CustomDateEditor(format, true));
        binder.registerCustomEditor(DonorPersonalInformation.class, "donor", new BloodBagController.DonorEditor());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/collect-blood", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String collectBlood(Model model) {
        bloodBag = new BloodBag();
        bloodBag.setBloodBagId(bloodBagService.generateBloodBagNumber());
        model.addAttribute(bloodBag);
        model.addAttribute("donors", donorService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("title", "Blood Bank : Collect Blood");
        return "bloodBag/collectBlood";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/collect-blood", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveBloodBag(Model model, @Valid BloodBag bloodBag, BindingResult result,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        bloodBagValidator.validate(bloodBag, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("donors", donorService.findAll());
            model.addAttribute("title", "Blood Bank : Collect Blood");
            return "bloodBag/collectBlood";
        }
        bloodBagService.saveBloodBag(bloodBag);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Blood bag saved.");
        return "redirect:/admin/blood-bag/stock";
    }
}
```

The Model Class

```
package com.bbms.web.models;

import com.bbms.web.models.donor.DonorPersonalInformation;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BLOOD_BAG")
public class BloodBag implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, name = "BLOOD_BAG_GENERATED_ID", length = 30)
    private String bloodBagId;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "COLLECTION_DATE", length = 20, nullable = true)
    private Date collectionDate;
    @Column(name = "RED_CELLS", length = 100, nullable = true)
    private String redCells;
    @Column(name = "WHITE_CELLS", length = 100, nullable = true)
    private String whiteCells;
    @Column(name = "PLATELETSS", length = 100, nullable = true)
    private String platelets;
    @Column(name = "PLASMA", length = 100, nullable = true)
    private String plasma;


    //Setters and Getters

}
```

The JSP File is

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h5>Collect Blood</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <sf:form class="form" commandName="bloodBag" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <c:set var="bloodBagIdHasBindError"><sf:errors path="bloodBagId"/></c:set>
                            <div class="form-group <c:if test="${!empty bloodBagIdHasBindError}" > has-error </c:if> ">
                                <sf:label path="bloodBagId" cssClass="control-label">Blood Bag Number</sf:label>
                                <sf:input path="bloodBagId" cssClass="form-control" palceholder="Blood Bag Number" />
                                <p><sf:errors path="bloodBagId" /></p>
                            </div>                    

                            <c:set var="collectionDateHasBindError"><sf:errors path="collectionDate"/></c:set>
                            <div class="form-group <c:if test="${!empty collectionDateHasBindError}" > has-error </c:if> ">
                                <sf:label path="collectionDate" cssClass="control-label">Date (yyyy/MM/dd)</sf:label>
                                <sf:input path="collectionDate" cssClass="form-control" palceholder="" />
                                <p><sf:errors path="collectionDate" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <c:set var="redCellsHasBindError"><sf:errors path="redCells"/></c:set>
                            <div class="form-group <c:if test="${!empty redCellsHasBindError}" > has-error </c:if> ">
                                <sf:label path="redCells" cssClass="control-label">Red Cells</sf:label>
                                <sf:input path="redCells" cssClass="form-control" palceholder="Red Cells" />
                                <p><sf:errors path="redCells" /></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <c:set var="whiteCellsHasBindError"><sf:errors path="whiteCells"/></c:set>
                            <div class="form-group <c:if test="${!empty whiteCellsHasBindError}" > has-error </c:if> ">
                                <sf:label path="whiteCells" cssClass="control-label">White Cells</sf:label>
                                <sf:input path="whiteCells" cssClass="form-control" palceholder="White Cells" />
                                <p><sf:errors path="whiteCells" /></p>
                            </div>                    
                            <c:set var="plateletsHasBindError"><sf:errors path="platelets"/></c:set>
                            <div class="form-group <c:if test="${!empty plateletsHasBindError}" > has-error </c:if> ">
                                <sf:label path="platelets" cssClass="control-label">Platelets</sf:label>
                                <sf:input path="platelets" cssClass="form-control" palceholder="Red Cells" />
                                <p><sf:errors path="platelets" /></p>
                            </div>                    
                            <c:set var="plasmaHasBindError"><sf:errors path="plasma"/></c:set>
                            <div class="form-group <c:if test="${!empty plasmaHasBindError}" > has-error </c:if> ">
                                <sf:label path="plasma" cssClass="control-label">Plasma</sf:label>
                                <sf:input path="plasma" cssClass="form-control" palceholder="Red Cells" />
                                <p><sf:errors path="plasma" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="" style="margin-top: 39px"> 
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">Save Blood Bag</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </sf:form>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely related to timezone settings - please note, that instead of Date type in your entity you should be using LocalDate from new Java API  (or Joda Time, if you need to run the application on older JVMs).

Please check your DB timezone settings, likely it's different than your server ones.

Comment: Yes it was a time zone problem. Thanks jderda

Comment: If that solved your issue, please mark my reply as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have already cast the vote for your answer, but it will be published when i get the rank. Thanks @ jderda.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java8, it would be better to use LocalDate/LocalTime/LocalDateTime instead old and hard to use Date class.

Add `compile org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.1.0.Final` dependency to your project.

Try not to use `Date` class any more.